# What is the numerical range of $A$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $A = \left( {\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
   0 & 0 & 0 & 1  \\
   0 & 0 & 1 & 0  \\
   0 & 1 & 0 & 0  \\
   1 & 0 & 0 & 0  \\
\end{array}} \right)$

What is the  numerical range of $A$?

Comment: Range of a matrix whats that new thing for me

Comment: @ArchisWelankar - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Numerical_range

Comment: Calculate the eigenvalues first.

Comment: @mlu - Why?         ....

Comment: Property 9 in the wikipedia reference

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint:** This matrix is symmetric $A^T=A$, so in particular $$A^TA=AA^T$$ which means that the matrix is normal (as real valued). So, its numerical range is the convex hull of its eigenvalues, see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Numerical_range#Properties) bullet 10. Now, $$\det(A-λΙ)=(λ^2-1)^2$$

Comment: Also ${A ^T}A=A^2$ is the unit matrix.